# Sequelize: How to Perform Both Schema and Data Migration Without Locking the DB in Production

Tags: database, sequelize.js, migration, schema, sequelize-cli

Due to updated requirements, I'm currently attempting to perform a database migration with two parts:

1. Add a new column to the relation, and
2. Update all the pre-existing records in the database with data pertaining to this new column.

My current approach is as follows:

1. Prepare a migration file to `addColumn`, and make the necesary foreign key associations (with attendant constraints). I do want the column to not be nullable, but if I do it at the point of the migration, then it will fail, 'cos the table already has records that don't satisfy the current requirements.
2. Prepare a `script.js` file (for example), that fetches all the records for this table, maps through them and adds data for the new column. This, I imagine, might be a time-intensive process — and might lock the database. Goes without saying that I'll use a transaction, by the way.
3. Perform another migration, this time to add the `allowNull: false` constraint, with the data migration done.

My question is: what are the things to look out for here? How could I potentially mess things up so badly for my production users if I ran this setup live?

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions from me:

1. Your application must be ready to be working with both cases when you are not yet migrated all the data and some of the records still miss the column value. This is especially true if you have a lot of data and can't migrate all the records quickly. You can split your feature delivery into smaller releases to achieve this.
2. You are not necessarily need to use db transactions. You need to make your migration idempotent instead. Because your code can handle both cases, while migration is running you can normally operate. You won't lock your table/records in this case and even if you fail in between you can continue after restart from the moment of failure.